# How do I loop dict and use the value as functions of an object?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary of values and initialize an object.
The dictionary values contains all the modules of the object, so how can I achieve something like this?

```
test_action = {
    '1': 'addition',
    '2': 'subtraction'
}

class test:
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def addition(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c

    def subtraction(self):
        return self.a - self.b - self.c


def main():
    xxx = test(10,5,1)
    for key,action in test_action.items():
        print(xxx.action())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to the functions as objects rather than strings, so that:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def addition(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c

    def subtraction(self):
        return self.a - self.b - self.c

test_action = {
    '1': test.addition,
    '2': test.subtraction
}

xxx = test(10,5,1)
for key, action in test_action.items():
    print(key, action(xxx))
```

would output:

```
1 16
2 4
```

Comment: the purpose was to have a list of actions in sequence (dictionary is not sorted) in a generic form, so that I can use range and perform the methods in sequence irregardless of the initialize object name.

i found another way after searching high and low,
        print(eval('xxx.' + action + '()'))

Comment: Using `eval` is generally discouraged due to security and performance concerns. Doesn't the code in my answer above accomplish the same thing?

Comment: ah...ok. I had some misunderstanding in the code. now it is clear. thanks. :)

Comment: thanks to your suggestion, i have also found out that this is also possible.
for key,action in test_action.items():
        store_test[action.__name__] = action(xxx)

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    xxx = test(10,5,1)
    for key,action in test_action.items():
        if hasattr(xxx, action):
            print "perforning: {}".format(action)
            print xxx.__getattribute__(action)()

#op
perforning: addition
16
perforning: subtraction
4
```

Comment: hi @daniel, did you check this?